# Positioning text below image

Tags: java, android, layout

I'm trying to put in RelativeLayout an image and text, and would like the text was down but over the image.

**My code**:

```
        RelativeLayout rl;
        //
        rl = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
        rl.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        rl.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setId(1);
        TextView textView = new TextView(mContext);
        textView.setId(2);
        //              
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        textView.setText(mTextMenu[position]);
        //
        rl.addView(imageView);
        //
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        //                  
        mParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, imageView.getId());            
        rl.addView(textView, mParams);
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: My code is not working, how do I make the text appears over the image? And how do I leave the text at the bottom of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve by changing the layout of the TextView:

```
        childParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(65, 25);
        childParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        childParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        rl.addView(textView, childParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use linear layout. Thats more appropriate for your case.

Comment: Hello the100rabh, thanks for the reply, but I want the text in front of the image and aligned at the bottom.

Comment: oh in that case I would suggest u to try using the layout XML for experimenting with the UI. I will give you a better understanding of the stuff.